# alignment is not working.

Tags: support, mathjax

I tried like this.

\begin{align}

y_{p}  &= $\ \frac{1}{D^2+D} (8cos2x-4sinx)\\$

&= $\ \frac{1}{D^2+D} 8cos2x$ -$\ \frac{1}{D^2+D} 4sinx\\ $

&= $\ 8\frac{1}{-4+D}cos2x$ - $\ 4\frac{1}{-1+D}sinx \\$

&= $\ 8\frac{D+4}{D^2-16}cos2x$ - $\ 4\frac{D+1}{D^2-1}sinx\\$

& = $\ 8\frac{D+4}{-20}cos2x$ - $\ 4\frac{D+1}{-2}sinx\\$

& = $\ -\frac{2}{5}(D+4)cos2x$ + $\ 2(D+1)sinx\\$

& = $\ -\frac{2}{5}(-2sin2x+4cos2x)$ + $\ 2(cosx+sinx)  \\$

& = $\ \frac{4}{5}(sin2x-2cos2x)$+$\ 2(sinx+cosx)\\$ 
\end{align}
Starting with 'dollar' before begin command and ending with 'dollar' after end command and ending each line with 'double blackslash'.

Comment: You are using it wrong, even on a normal $\rm\LaTeX$ standard, this code is simply wrong.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5024#5024

Comment: i watched it. but what were my mistakes? @AsafKaragila

Comment: You don't need dollars on each line. The minus should be *inside* your equation, it is a math symbol after all. While we're at it, `\cos` and `\sin` are their own commands too.

Comment: if i don't write dollars sign in each line then how the fractions or sin, cos etc will work? @AsafKaragila

Comment: I have [edited your post on the main](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3627223/revisions) to get to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3627223/3). I am not sure whether it is close to what you wanted to get. If you still have some questions, feel free to use the [MathJax chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/13752).

Comment: @MartinSleziak yes I wanted exactly this. but how did you find my post? :D

Comment: From [your profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/568656/manjoy-das) on the main. It is [among your recent answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/568656/manjoy-das?tab=answers&sort=activity).

Comment: can you please tell me what were my mistakes? @MartinSleziak Sometimes it becomes too complicated.

Comment: I left some comments on that [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/13752/2020/4/15).